# reformat single run-on line with line breaks and indent

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript file where all the line breaks and spacing has been removed, so the whole thing is on a single line.  I'm looking for a utility that will add back in line breaks and indents to turn this into something human-readable, but not having much luck.

This issue in particular deals with javascript, but I will probably run into the same issue in the future with different languages; a tool that handles multiple languages would be preferred

For example, when given this

```
var h=Ext.util,j=Ext.each,g=true,i=false;h.Observable=function(){var k=this,l=k.events;if(k.listeners){k.on(k.listeners);delete k.listeners}k.events=l||{}};//etc etc
```

The tool should reformat it like this

```
var h = Ext.util, j = Ext.each, g = true, i = false;
h.Observable = function(){
    var k = this, l = k.events;
    if (k.listeners){
        k.on(k.listeners);
        delete k.listeners
    }
    k.events = l || {} 
};
//etc etc
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be interested in either [jsBeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) or [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)'s "Tidy Up" functionality.

Comment: ooo, very nice.  Do you know of anything that handles other languages, in particular python and C?

Comment: @steve: We have a family of formatters, one specific to each language; using language precise parsers and prettyprinters they won't break your code.  See http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Formatters You can try something like astyle (astyle.sourceforge.net) which claims to handle many languages, but since it doesn't know the precise details of each language, I don't know if they (can) claim that it doesn't damage your code.